# Ionic application works perfectly on one phone but crashes mobile OS on another phone

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

When testing an Ionic application on my OnePlus 2 (with latest Android update), the application works perfectly fine. However, when testing the phone on an LG-L70 not only does the application not work but the phone starts going nuts. The screen flickers until it is rendered unusable and blacks out. Even when removing the battery and back in again and resetting, the phone may or may not switch on. When the application is removed from the phone, everything goes back to normal. It is also worth noting that battery power is consumed at a much higher rate and the phone heats up considerably.

What could be causing this weird and potentially dangerous issue? Could it be a plugin that is not compatible with older Android versions that is causing this, or something similar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: degrade your android version.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: go to AndroidManifest file in platforms folder for android
 and <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" /> set this version then make a build and test .

Comment: A proper way would be to put it in `config.xml` otherwise it could be overwritten by build. Here is the code `<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
</platform>`

Comment: Android with version older than 4.3 doesn't support the fancy ionic very well because of old webkit version. Did you try Crosswalk?

Comment: No I have not actually. How can it help?